# .htaccess issue when creating users profile?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using .htaccess code in order to pass pages titles to the url and then retrieve them with php from mysql tables when the page loads.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I am using this php code to explode the url and get the title:

```
$passed_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$passed_url = explode("/", $passed_url);
$passed_url = end($passed_url);
```

Now I want to create a user profile page like so `www.website.com/users/User_name_in_here`
how do I check with php if this is a users page or it is just a regular page which can be writer like so: `www.webiste.com/Page_title_in_here`
is there a better way to do this ?(I am just a starter in php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to check `$passed_url[1]`. If it's 'users' then you know you're on the users page.

A better way would be to use index.php as a front controller and pass the request to a controller based on the request uri. there are a number of ways to do this.

Some frameworks map the uri to a class::method. So your url would be changed to `/users/view/username` and the `users::view` would be called.

I prefer to write regular expressions and which ever regular expression is matched controls which controller is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually change your Rewrite Engine `.htaccess` file this way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)-(.*)\.ptf$ ./?page=$1&id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.ptf$ ./?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./?page=$1&id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

So, this rule, what it exactly does is:

when the `URL` is `www.website.com/Page_title_in_here`,

it goes to `www.website.com/?page=Page_title_in_here`

and when you put this way, `www.website.com/users-User_name_in_here`,

it redirects to `www.website.com/?page=users&id=User_name_in_here`

So you can manipulate with the `$_GET["page"]` and `$_GET["page"]` variables!

What say? I do this way. Hope this helps you!